# How to find coordinates from <line> element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

In the webbrowser I need to extract this element:

```
<line stroke="#003088" stroke-width="15.562500357627869" stroke-linecap="round" marker-end="url(#arrowhead-pb)" opacity="0.4" x1="166.00000381469727" y1="431.6000099182129" x2="166.00000381469727" y2="309.17500710487366" cgHash="531.2000122070312,531.2000122070312,c2,c4,paleBlue"></line>
```

This element is not interactable but I still need so save the x1, x2, y1, y2 coordinates into variables. The only find option that worked for me was driver.find_element_by_tag_name('line') but this return the coordinates {'x': 611, 'y': 372} which is clearly not what I want.

My question: is there any way I can extract the exact coordinates from the webbrowser? Mainly x1, x2, y1, y2.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<line>`](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_line.asp) attribute is associated with the [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) elements which are from the [**SVG**](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) namespace. As an example:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

---

To print the value of *`x1`* coordinate you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg line").get_attribute("x1"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `name()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='line']").get_attribute("x1"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `local-name()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='title']").get_attribute("x1"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574316/how-to-write-a-locator-using-span-in-selenium-webdriver-python/57574859#57574859) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.name[title='Download']"))).get_attribute("x1"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `name()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='line']"))).get_attribute("x1"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `local-name()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='title']"))).get_attribute("x1"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [interacting with SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java) in:

- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)
- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)
- [Creating XPATH for svg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024052/creating-xpath-for-svg-tag/49024531#49024531)
- [Reading title tag in svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544775/reading-title-tag-in-svg/63544849#63544849)

Answer (score 0):

to get x you can use: ( similarly do for y , z etc)

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('line').get_attribute("x")
```

### you can get any element attribute , x , y etc are not coordinates but attribute of that element